# How to use jQuery to grab the values of checkboxes and spit them into a different form field

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have a form that contains a bunch of checkboxes.  Before submitting the form, I'd like to grab the values of the checkboxes and stick them into a text field, then submit that.

So I might have:
   Red
   Orange
X  Yellow
   Blue
X  Green

And I'd like my textfield to end up with the content "Yellow, Green" .

This doesn't seem too complicated, but I am totally out of my league.  I already use jQuery for a few other things so I have the framework ready, if that makes it easer.

Thanks for any advice --

Comment: Just a note, please use the "add comment" option to discuss an answer instead of adding a new answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use this code:

```
$(function(){
    $('#YourFormID').bind('submit',function(){
        var serializedCheckboxes = '';
        $("input[type=checkbox]").each(function() {
         if($(this).attr("checked")) {
            serializedCheckboxes += (serializedCheckboxes != '' ? ', ' : '') + $(this).attr("value");
         }
        });
        $("input[name=allchecks]").attr("value", serializedCheckboxes);
    });
});
```

It starts when page is loaded and bind to "submit" event of your form correct function

Comment: Forgot, would be wise to use ,join(stuff,',') instead of manually building it into a local string variable.

Answer (score 0):

First hack at it (without testing):

```
var serializedCheckboxes = '';
$("input type='checkbox'").each(function() {
 if($(this).attr("checked")) {
  serializedCheckboxes += $(this).attr("value") + ',';
 }
});

$("input name='allchecks').attr("value", serializedCheckboxes);
```

Answer (score 0):

fix to Josh code:

```
var serializedCheckboxes = '';
$("input[type=checkbox]").each(function() {
 if($(this).attr("checked")) {
  serializedCheckboxes += (serializedCheckboxes != '' ? ', ' : '') + $(this).attr("value");
 }
});

$("input[name=allchecks]").attr("value", serializedCheckboxes);
```

After my fix you should not get extra "," after last option.

Answer (score 0):

So, more improvements. Add a class name (in my example "colorCheckBoxes") to all checkboxes with colors in your form (if checkboxes exists) - this help avoid problems when you want to use different additional checkboxes in your form for other purposes than selecting colors. Then use this code:

```
$(function(){
    $('#YourFormID').bind('submit',function(){
        var serializedCheckboxes = '';
        $(this).find("input[type=checkbox]").filter('.colorCheckBoxes').each(function() {
         if($(this).attr("checked")) {
            serializedCheckboxes += (serializedCheckboxes != '' ? ', ' : '') + $(this).attr("value");
         }
        });
        if (serializedCheckboxes != '')
            $(this).find("input[name=allchecks]").attr("value", serializedCheckboxes);
    });
});
```